# Excel VBA - How to concatenate data in multiple dynamic number of rows and multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to concatenate the data dynamically using Excel VBA Macro and have no idea how to handle the data spread over varying number of rows and multiple columns.

Here is the image of sample data and output required...  <sub>(Click to enlarge.)</sub>
[image: screenshot]

Assuming that:

1. Each new row required in the output begins in the sample data with a serial number. However in the sample data the number of rows for each output data varies, as in the image you see, the first output row is spread over 3 rows in sample data, similarly the second and third output rows are spread over 5 rows and 4 rows in the sample data.
2. The `columns A, B, C, D` should have their output in `column M`
3. The `columns E, F` should have their output in `column N`
4. The `columns G, H` should have their output in `column O`
5. The `columns I, J, K` should have their output in `column P`

I need dynamic VBA code which prompts for:

1. Number of output columns
2. Output column begins with column__
3. Input column range for each output column.

Here is the code which I have worked out, to concatenate the range with empty cells in between, where the input range and output cell is selected manually.

```
Sub Concatenate()
'Creates a basic CONCATENATE formula with no options
Call Concatenate_Formula(True, True)
End Sub

Sub Concatenate_Formula(bConcat As Boolean, bOptions As Boolean)

Dim rSelected As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim sArgs As String
Dim bCol As Boolean
Dim bRow As Boolean
Dim sArgSep As String
Dim sSeparator As String
Dim rOutput As Range
Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim lTrim As Long
Dim sTitle As String

'Set variables
Set rOutput = ActiveCell
bCol = False
bRow = False
sSeparator = ""
sTitle = IIf(bConcat, "CONCATENATE", "Ampersand")

'Prompt user to select cells for formula
On Error Resume Next
Set rSelected = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "Select cells to create formula", _
                Title:=sTitle & " Creator", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
'Only run if cells were selected and cancel button was not pressed
If Not rSelected Is Nothing Then

    'Set argument separator for concatenate or ampersand formula
    sArgSep = IIf(bConcat, ",", "&")

    'Prompt user for absolute ref and separator options
  If bOptions Then
        sSeparator = " "
    End If

    'Create string of cell references
    For Each c In rSelected.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        sArgs = sArgs & c.Address(bRow, bCol) & sArgSep
        If sSeparator <> "" Then
            sArgs = sArgs & Chr(34) & sSeparator & Chr(34) & sArgSep
        End If
    Next

    'Trim extra argument separator and separator characters
    lTrim = IIf(sSeparator <> "", 4 + Len(sSeparator), 1)
    sArgs = Left(sArgs, Len(sArgs) - lTrim)

    'Create formula
    'Warning - you cannot undo this input
    'If undo is needed you could copy the formula string
    'to the clipboard, then paste into the activecell using Ctrl+V
    If bConcat Then
        rOutput.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & sArgs & ")"
    Else
        rOutput.Formula = "=" & sArgs
    End If
    Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
 rSelected = ""
End If
End Sub
```

How to modify this code to work across, multiple columns, and variable number of rows, as shown in the image?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** This is a place for programmers to ask/answer questions when a solution to the problem can't be found elsewhere. Please see the [tour] as well as "[ask]", plus there's important tips about **providing examples** at "[mcve]". Please show that you made an **effort** to find a solution yourself before asking for help (on a _specific_ issue). You can always [edit] your question to include details (code/screenshots/etc) showing what you've tried so far. More info: [help/on-topic]. See also [these great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: ...also, some explanation as to *what you're trying to do* would be helpful.  I assume by the bizarre layout of your screenshot that this is a homework question? If so, that's okay, but you still need to show that you've made an effort.  (This isn't a *"free code writing service"*!) You said you just don't know how to handle the blanks... so how would you handle it if there were *no* blanks?  (See also: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)")

Comment: one more link: ["Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8112776) ... but don't get discouraged -- this site take some getting used to!  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @ashleedawg, As suggested, I have edited the question and included the code which I could figure out for concatenating a range of cells with empty cells in between.

Comment: So that code runs properly on your example data?  I still have some unanswered questions in my comments above -- I'm having trouble figuring out what you're trying to do.  ***Did you try any of the solutions further down on [the source page from your code sample](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/923661-excel-intelligent-concatenation)?***

Comment: Yes, It works on the example data, but to get M1 with the above code we need to select A1 to D3 manually, and for M2, A4 to D8 and so on.

Comment: I need the code to recognize the range dynamically, where for the range the columns are specified on prompt and the rows are recognized, based on the serial number it begins with. This avoids the repetition of the manual process.

The data similar to the example image has been populated by the pdf to excel converter, which failed to organize the data in each box into a single cell. There are hundreds of pages, and I really need help with the code. @ashleedawg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the layout of the data is exactly as same as shown in the image, please give this a try...

```
Sub ConcatenateData()
Dim lr As Long, cnt As Long, n As Long, dlr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range, ConcatRng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String, str4 As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Columns("M:P").ClearContents
Columns(1).Insert
With Range("A1:A" & lr)
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(B1,1)+0),1,NA())"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).ClearContents
    .Value = .Value
End With
n = Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas.Count
For Each Rng In Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas
    cnt = cnt + 1
    If cnt <> n Then
        Set ConcatRng = Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlDown).Offset(-1))
        Set rng1 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 1).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 4)
        Set rng2 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 5).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 2)
        Set rng3 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 7).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 2)
        Set rng4 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 9).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 3)
    Else
        Set ConcatRng = Range(Rng, Range("A" & lr))
        Set rng1 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 1).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 4)
        Set rng2 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 5).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 2)
        Set rng3 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 7).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 2)
        Set rng4 = ConcatRng.Offset(, 9).Resize(ConcatRng.Cells.Count, 3)
    End If

    For Each cell In rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
        str1 = str1 & " " & cell.Value
    Next cell

    For Each cell In rng2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
        str2 = str2 & " " & cell.Value
    Next cell

    For Each cell In rng3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
        str3 = str3 & " " & cell.Value
    Next cell

    For Each cell In rng4.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
        str4 = str4 & " " & cell.Value
    Next cell
    If Range("N1").Value = "" Then
        dlr = 1
    Else
        dlr = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Row
    End If
    Range("N" & dlr).Value = str1
    Range("O" & dlr).Value = str2
    Range("P" & dlr).Value = str3
    Range("Q" & dlr).Value = str4
    str1 = ""
    str2 = ""
    str3 = ""
    str4 = ""
Next Rng
Columns(1).Delete
Columns("M:P").AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. @sktneer, It works

Comment: @John You're welcome. Glad it worked as desired.